# PL/SQL Function to return a customer name given order id

Tags: oracle

/*Create a PL/SQL function get_customer_name that returns the
customer’s name given Order ID.*/

/*When I call the function I receive the customer ID as the result. The function should return the customer name. What am I missing?*/

--Oracle PL/SQL Function:--

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_name(cust_id IN VARCHAR)
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
cname VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
    SELECT customer_id INTO cname FROM s_order_t o WHERE o.order_id = cust_id;
    RETURN cname;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO SUCH EMPLOYEE');
RETURN -1;
END;
```

/*Write an anonymous PL/SQL program to call
this function with some Order ID as input, and print out the results.*/
--Function Call:--

```sql
DECLARE
cname VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
    cname := get_customer_name (1010);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cname);
END;
```

Comment: It's probably because you're doing `SELECT customer_id INTO cname...`. What table and column is used to store the customer names?

Comment: I think you miss the link with the table `customer`? And you also need to join these tables.

Comment: Table name is s_customer_t and the column name is customer_name

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting the customer's name; you probably need to `JOIN` to a `customers` table and get the `name` column (assuming that is what they are called):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customer_name(
  cust_id IN S_ORDER_T.ORDER_ID%TYPE
) RETURN CUSTOMERS.NAME%TYPE
IS 
  cname CUSTOMERS.NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT name
  INTO   cname
  FROM   s_order_t o
         INNER JOIN customers c
         ON (o.customer_id = c.id)
  WHERE o.order_id = cust_id;

  RETURN cname;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE s_order_t (
  order_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id REFERENCES customers
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO s_order_t VALUES (1010, 1);
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  cname CUSTOMERS.NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  cname := get_customer_name (1010);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cname);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Alice
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0075d7033929fa983dd723535cc0988)*

Comment: Thanks. It worked with some minor changes.